# Ĉu antaŭ aŭ antaŭe?

Tags: word-difference

> 1. Mi komencis lerni Esperanton **antaŭ unu jaro**.
> 2. Mi komencis lerni Esperanton **unu jaron antaŭe**.

Kio estas la diferenco de la du frazoj? Ĉu ili havas malsamajn signifojn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laŭ mia kompreno, la fina senco de viaj du frazoj estas preskaŭ la sama.

La frazo 1. *Mi komencis lerni Esperanton **antaŭ unu jaro***, signifas, ke la lernado komencis je unu jaro pli frue ol nun.

La frazo 2. *Mi komencis lerni Esperanton **unu jaron antaŭe***, signifas, ke la lernado komencis pli frue ol iu alia tempo. Se la tempo estas *nun*, la lernado komencis je unu jaro pli frue ol nun. Sed depende de la kunteksto la tempopunkto povas esti alia ol nun. Ekz: *Mi iris al mia unua Esperanto-kongreso en 2015, ĉar mi komencis lerni Esperanton unu jaron antaŭe*. Do vi komencis lerni en 2014, ne en 2019.

---

### Aldona klarigo pri kial oni aldonas N-finaĵon al "jaro" (laŭ peto de Qàtrè)

La resuma klarigo pri tio estas, ke ***unu jaron antaŭe*** = ***en unu jaro antaŭe***. La detala klarigo troveblas en [12.2.4. N por tempopunkto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/tempopunkto.html), el kiu mi libere prenas la jenajn ekzemplojn:

*Unu tagon estis forta pluvo* = *En unu tago estis forta pluvo*

*Li naskiĝis la dudek duan de Februaro* = *Li naskiĝis en la dudek dua (tago) de Februaro*

Comment: Dankegon pro via respondo. Nun mi komprenis tion tute, danke al via komento. Mi pardonpetas, sed havas alian demandon rilate al tiu ĉi temo: Kial oni aldonas -n finaĵon al "jaro"? Tio certe nek estas objekto de la frazo, nek intencas montri la movadon. Do, kial?

Answer (score 1):

```
    1. Mi komencis lerni Esperanton antaŭ unu jaro.

    2. Mi komencis lerni Esperanton unu jaron antaŭe.
```

La du estas ĝustaj. La dua havas tamen alian signifon, kiu emigas min demandi "antaŭ kio?".

*Tempa antaŭ* postulas almenaŭ du tempopunktojn. En la unua frazo vi havas *nun -> antaŭ unu jaro*. En la dua, depende de la kunteksto, la unua tempo povus esti io alia, ne nepre nun.

Ekzemple (imagu ke vi loĝas en Atlantido):

```
  La UK en Atlantido okazis en 1540. Mi komencis lerni Esperanton unu jaron antaŭe.
```

Do, la kuntektsto ĵus igis vian lernadon komenciĝi en 1539. Tio estas la ĉefa malsamo inter la du frazoj.

Jen ekzemploj el Tekstaro (nur Zamenhofaj):

```
Du fojojn antaŭe en mia vivo mi jam vidis tiun aĵon
```

Antaŭ nun.

```
Venis la tago de la enterigo. Kelkajn noktojn antaŭe ŝi ne dormis
```

Antaŭ la enterigo, multe pli frue ol nun.

```
oni nun prikalkulas la batojn de la koro multajn jarojn antaŭe kaj oni diras al la pulso: ĝis tie kaj ne plu!
```

Tio ĉi okazas antaŭ la forpaso, iam dum la vivo, por poste bone porciumi la batojn, por vivi pli longe. Do, ĉi foje *multajn jarojn antaŭe* tamen rilatas estontecon.

Comment: Dankon Sinjoro Trápani pro via bona respondo. En viaj ekzemploj, vi priskribis paroli Esperanton je la jaroj 1539-1540! (Mi scias ke vi intencis skribi 1939-1940) Tio estas iel interesa! Imagu se oni parolus Esperanton dum la 16a jarcento, kiel estus Esperanto en nia jarcento! :-) Dankon.

Comment: Mi ja celis 1540. La ideo de la ekzemplo estis ĝuste montri la influon de la kunteksto en la dua frazo, kaj mi vole skribis ion ajn. La UK de Atlantido neniam okazis ;)